# How to filter rows having array of struct?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataFrame with array of struct so I just want to filter columns or we can say select column in array of struct from the array of struct but is it possible as I am iterating through row .
Schema

```
 root 
     |-- day: long (nullable = true)
     |-- table_row: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ADMISSION_NUM: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- SOURCE_CODE: string (nullable = true)
```

What I am doing is that I am iterating through Rows Can we select the array columns row wise . I only want to know how this is possible

```
def keepColumnInarray(columns: Set[String], row: Row): Row = {
      //Some 
    }
```

Example If I want to keep column "Data" Then keepColumnInarray will only select this

Output Schema

```
 root 
     |-- day: long (nullable = true)
     |-- table_row: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: There is no array of struct in your example, 'table_row' is of type struct.

Comment: Sorry , I will update the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### spark >= 2.4

```scala
df.withColumn("table_row", expr("TRANSFORM (table_row, x -> named_struct('DATE', x.DATE))")
```

this will convert

```
table_row: array
struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ADMISSION_NUM: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- SOURCE_CODE: string (nullable = true)
```

to

```
table_row: array
 struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
```

### Update-1 (based on comments)

### spark < 2.4

Use below UDF to select columns-

```scala
 val df = spark.range(2).withColumnRenamed("id", "day")
      .withColumn("table_row", expr("array(named_struct('DATE', 'sample_date'," +
        " 'ADMISSION_NUM', 'sample_adm_num', 'SOURCE_CODE', 'sample_source_code'))"))
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

//   
//   +---+---------------------------------------------------+
//   |day|table_row                                          |
//   +---+---------------------------------------------------+
//   |0  |[[sample_date, sample_adm_num, sample_source_code]]|
//   |1  |[[sample_date, sample_adm_num, sample_source_code]]|
//   +---+---------------------------------------------------+
//   
//   root
//   |-- day: long (nullable = false)
//   |-- table_row: array (nullable = false)
//   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
//   |    |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = false)
//   |    |    |-- ADMISSION_NUM: string (nullable = false)
//   |    |    |-- SOURCE_CODE: string (nullable = false)
//
```

```scala
    def keepColumnInarray(columnsToKeep: Seq[String], rows: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) = {
      rows.map(r => {
        new GenericRowWithSchema(r.getValuesMap(columnsToKeep).values.toArray,
          StructType(r.schema.filter(s => columnsToKeep.contains(s.name))))
      })
    }

    val keepColumns = udf((columnsToKeep: Seq[String], rows: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) =>
      keepColumnInarray(columnsToKeep, rows)
      , ArrayType(StructType(StructField("DATE", StringType) :: Nil)))

    val processedDF = df
      .withColumn("table_row_new", keepColumns(array(lit("DATE")), col("table_row")))
    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

//    
//    +---+---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
//    |day|table_row                                          |table_row_new  |
//    +---+---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
//    |0  |[[sample_date, sample_adm_num, sample_source_code]]|[[sample_date]]|
//    |1  |[[sample_date, sample_adm_num, sample_source_code]]|[[sample_date]]|
//    +---+---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
//    
//    root
//    |-- day: long (nullable = false)
//    |-- table_row: array (nullable = false)
//    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
//    |    |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = false)
//    |    |    |-- ADMISSION_NUM: string (nullable = false)
//    |    |    |-- SOURCE_CODE: string (nullable = false)
//    |-- table_row_new: array (nullable = true)
//    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//    |    |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
//
```

Comment: Thanks For your suggestion , But I am doing some operations at Row level and want to select these columns at row level using a list of column names , so can it be possible ?

Comment: above is a row level operation, this will convert ```table_row: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ADMISSION_NUM: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- SOURCE_CODE: string (nullable = true)``` to ```table_row: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
     |  ```

Comment: Like you are not understanding , I want to do some operations on the row that is why I want to select only these columns . Please suggest if this is possible to do that at row level

Comment: I think, its better if you provide sample i/p and expected o/p. The terminologies might create ambiguity in understanding

Comment: Output will be same as Input , But I want to do some operation at intermediate level so I am temporary removing these columns to get some calculations using remaining columns

Comment: Check update. The solution will work for spark >= 2.4.0

Comment: Thanks , but what If I have a function                                                                              def keepColumnInarray(columns: Set[String], row: Row): Row = {
      //Some 
    }                                                                                                                                                 so How can we do if I want row to remove that columns

Comment: I believe, `columns: Set[String]`  will contain columns to keep from struct in an array, is it?

Comment: Yeah Thanks , But it is possble to update that row instead of creating new column ??

Comment: That is just for the demo, so that you can see the difference in a line. use the same name  in like - `val processedDF = df
      .withColumn("table_row", keepColumns(array(lit("DATE")), col("table_row")))
    processedDF.show(false)` if you are not interested in creating new column. Also, please upvote + accept if it helps you

Comment: I cannot upvote but I have accepted your answer , thanks for ur help

Comment: I just want to confirm can we do like this   def keepColumnInarray(columnsToKeep: Seq[String], rows: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) = {
      rows.map(r => {
     r.schema.filter(s => columnsToKeep.contains(s.name))))
      })
    }

Comment: Instead of  creating new column can we filter the row itself ??

Comment: if you follow that route, there also you need to create new row having the different schema. Please note that you wanted to transform both data and schema, so calling `df.map(row =>..)` and `df.withColumn(..)` is one and the same thing